# Adding multiple text lines with 'convert'

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I'm trying to place multiple lines of text on an image, but the following produces the following error:

```
convert convert: Non-conforming drawing primitive definition (\) [No such file or directory].
```

And it will only add the first line of text. Here is my command in my script:

```
convert weekback.png  -font Helvetica-Narrow-BoldOblique -pointsize 208 \
          -draw "fill black  text 450,275 '$day1'  \ 
        fill black  text 900,275 '$day2' " \
          test.png
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try without the line continuation characters `\\` Do you still get the error?

Comment: If I combine the last three lines (removing the '\' characters , I dont get the error. But it would be a lot more convenient if I can separate the lines (I have a lot more text to add) Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the continuation needs to be escaped? `\\\` somewhere in there. I would try one continuation character at a time, til you find which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Definitely doesn't need to be escaped, but after I tried it, I changed it back to how I had it originally. Now it works... I have no explanation

Comment: The problem in the command above is that there is a space char after the first continuation character, making it a normal backslash. You must be sure that the newline is *immediatly* after the continuation `\` to have it working.

Comment: Ah, I see.. Space is a great thing, too bad you can't see it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the command above is that there is a space after the first continuation character, making it a normal backslash.

You can suspect this noticing that the backslash character is interpreted by `convert`, when it should not even see any continuation char (the shell take care of it).

You must be sure that the newline is immediately  after the continuation `\` to have it working.